# What is the set of quotients of arguments of algebraic numbers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.
What is $$X = \left\{\frac{\theta}{\varphi} \ |\ e^{i\theta}, e^{i\varphi} \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}\ \wedge\ \theta, \varphi \in ]-\pi,\pi]\ \wedge\ \varphi \neq 0\right\}?$$

I can show that $\mathbb{Q} \varsubsetneq X \varsubsetneq{\mathbb{R}}$, but I don't understand more about those numbers.

Comment: I doubt there is a simple description. Even argument of $1+2i$, which is $\arctan(2)$, is a "complicated" number.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If $\alpha$ is algebraic, then so is $\sqrt{\alpha/\overline{\alpha}}$. The latter has the same argument and norm 1.